# Best way to capture handwriting and turn it into typed text

Tags: c#, kinect

I would like to write a program which captures motion using a Kinect and then saves the path of motion and then converts the image created into text.

I am not sure if OCR will be the best way to do it as in all probability the quality of the image will be quite low.

Is there some system anyone could suggest. Also any tips on how to achieve it. Cheers

edit:

Windows Journal does pretty much exactly what I want.

Comment: the software you are proposing will be part OCR

Answer (score 1):

You need a sensor like Kinect and use its APIs to capture the motion. This is very specific to the sensor and motion capturing technology. I don't think you can write a motion capturing technology without third party API using C#.

Comment: I don't think he was implying that he was not going to use the Kinect API. He's looking for a method to convert the data it gives him into text by analyzing the motions like handwriting recognition.

Comment: Yes I am planning to use the API with the Kinect, I already have it running as an alternative input device which allows me to control my laptop to a degree, it's quite good fun for angry birds for instance, but am now trying to move it on.

Answer (score 1):

I fail to see the advantage that the Kinect can give you here.

You have to define first what kind of input this system will have: Will it be the RGB image of a character for example or something more complicated like tracked hand position through time?

If you want to use the Kinect for its depth map, then what you are trying to do seems more like gesture recognition (and mapping of each gesture to a character) to me rather than OCR.

***Edit for the gesture recognition way:***

I haven't implemented anything myself on that, so I can not really give you clear directions or proposals. There exist a couple of papers on the subject [(google scholar search)](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=gesture+recognition+kinect&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C44) that take advantage of the available depth info rather than working with 2D images. I would guess that the DIY way would be to get as many training samples as possible for each gesture, train your classifier ([wikipedia on supervised learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supervised_learning)) and then test your new samples.

If you don't feel so adventurous, you could start by testing some code samples that exist:

- The *hand tracking sample from OpenNI* -you can see an example [here](http://vimeo.com/21401266), I think it recognizes some gestures too- .
- [Candescent NUI](http://candescentnui.codeplex.com/) "Hand and finger tracking with Kinect depth data", I don't think it includes any recognition, but maybe it can help you get better data.
- The [Kinect for Windows Developer Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/develop/developer-downloads.aspx) could contain something useful, but to tell you the truth I haven't checked it out.

I can see the gesture recognition approach being very tricky though. There has to be a significant variation between the gestures, otherwise, taking into acount the Kinect low resolution and noise issues, even if you get a very large number of training samples, it could still fail. Imagine writing 'i' or 'l' for example. Or the difference between 'o' and 'a' (depending on your handwriting of course). The scale is so small and the moving of hands so trivial that I don't know if a classifier -even a powerful one- could catch that kind of variations.

Comment: I am probably trying to get gesture recognition rather than ocr. I was thinking about doing it this way, if you could suggest anything. I was thinking of doing it both ways though so you could write on paper and hold it up to the camera.